# Is federation a valid approach for cross-domain SSO In case all the RPs and the STS are developed internally?

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, ws-federation, federation

I need to implement Single Sign On feature for several internal web applications which are not deployed on the same domain.

Is federation a good solution in my case? Or it is only used if I want to federate the authentication to an external IdP.

I mean I want to create a custom WIF STS and make all the applications claims-aware RPs.

I'm thinking of it because I don't want to use custom solutions or third party libraries. WIF seems to have a straightforward solution integrated with .Net Framework.

Is my suggestion correct? Or this is an incorrect use for WIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - a solution with WIF / STS will work even if it's only internal.

Beware of security if you roll your own.

You may want to look at ADFS or [IdentityServer](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2).

Going this route will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thinktecture is just all what I needed